# Integrate Alamofire 2 Manually without using Framework

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

I recently upgraded to Swift 2 and XCode 7.
I was using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#manually) just by copying `Alamofire.swift` in my project.
But now I want to use Alamofire 2 and I downloaded and got latest `Alamofire.swift`.

I am getting a lot of errors in Alamofire.swift like:

> Use of undeclared type 'Request'

[image: error screenshot]

Also `Method` was an enum of HttpMethods, but now its typeAlias for `COpaquePointer`
[image: error2 screenshot]

I know that it can be done through CocoaPods but I don't want to use frameworks.
Whats the best way to integrate it now?

P.S.: I want to support iOS 8+

Comment: you need to return a NSMutableURLRequest

Comment: @longbow I think changing their source code is not recommended. And there are few other errors also. Is that the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You cant just include the Alamofire.swift file, you still need the whole package.

How should Alamofire.swift know where "Request" is, if it's methods are in Request.swift?

Comment: But the same thing was working before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must download all .swift files from Alamofire repository. Between Alamofire 1 and 2 there are lots of things that changed. For example `Request` and `responseJSON` block returns three things, `NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?,Result<AnyObject>` struct which has both the json data as `json.value` and `json.error` as `ErrorType`

Following code example shows how to use it with Xcode 7 and Swift 2

```
var defaultCfg: NSURLSessionConfiguration  {
    let cfg = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    cfg.HTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    cfg.HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy.Always
    cfg.URLCache = nil
    cfg.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0", "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.5"]
    return cfg
}
self.mngr = Manager(configuration: cfg)
    self.mngr.request(.GET, url,parameters:parameters)
        .responseJSON { (req, res, json) in
            if(json.error != nil) {
              //  NSLog("Error: \(error)")
                failure(res, json.value, someerroryouset)
                return

            }
            else {
                let jsond = JSON(json.value!)
```

Comment: For more information about the changes in Alamofire 2.0 https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%202.0%20Migration%20Guide.md